# SAS, sum with missing values

Tags: sas, sum

```
data test;
input A B C D$ E;
datalines;

. 70 .   Mike 2
1 80 21  Tony 3
2 10 0   .    4
3 .  0   Lew  .
3 9  4   .    .
;
run;

data test2;
set test;
Total=A+B+C;
run;

data test3;
set test;
if A=. then A=0;
if B=. then B=0;
if C=. then C=0;
Total=A+B+C;
run;
```

I want to sum column A B C but they have missing values, so I have to replace all missings with 0 first (in test3) so that I can get a number. Is there any elegant way to do it? My method looks very awkward. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your functions so you don't have to replace the missing values.

`SUM` function should do it - notice the difference in your output via the two methods shown below.

```
data out;
set test;
sum_func = sum(A,B,C);
sum = A+B+C;
keep sum: A B C;
run;
```